# How do I call DotNet Core API HealthCheck in combination with Url parameters

Tags: asp.net-core-3.1

I added a health check in my ASP.NET Core service (using .NET Core 3.1):

```
endpoints.MapHealthChecks("healthcheck", new HealthCheckOptions()
{
   Predicate = _ => true,
   ResponseWriter = ResponseWriter.WriteResponse
});
```

The health check works on http://localhost/healthcheck (there is no problem here, this works fine)

The problem is that I want to have it bound to a certain controller:

```
[Route("[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class TestController : ControllerBase
```

Now I want the health check to be accessible under https://localhost/Test/healthcheck
The obvious answer is to set the mapping to "/Test/healthcheck" but there is a problem when there is a GET handler like this:

```
[HttpGet("{param}")]
public ActionResult GetTest(string param)
```

Because with this, accessing https://localhost/Test/healthcheck will call this GET handler with "healthcheck" as value for *param* and the actual health check cannot be reached.

Since in my case the accepted values for *param* is a predefined list, I though I could simply write an if statement to do the health check if *param* equals "healthcheck" but I didn't find a way to run the health check within the controller.

Is there a better way how to do this?
Or is this not even possible?